# Rails helper path not working when using to_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't get my index page to load or simply show helper path to work.  If I just use a `to_param` with a field that's in the class's attributes, like for example `first_name`, I can get this to work.  Problem seems to be that I'm creating the data for an object's attribute (`full_name`) by joining two fields (`first_name` and `last_name`) together using a `before_validation` method in the model.  Based on troubleshooting, I know that's what's likely wrong but don't know how to fix.  Any advice?

Error Message is always along the lines of:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"artists", :full_name=>#<Artist id: 2, full_name: "John">} missing required keys: [:full_name]
```

Model

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord

 before_validation :fullname  

 def fullname
   self.full_name = "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
 end

 def to_param
  full_name
 end

end
```

Routes:

```
resources :artists, only: [:show, :index], param: :full_name, constraints: { full_name: /[\w]+/ }
```

Artist Controller:

```
before_action :set_artist, only: [:show]


def set_artist
        @artist = Artist.find_by(full_name: params[:full_name])
    end
```

Views (Index.html.erb):

```
<% @artists.each do |x| %>
   <%= link_to "name", artist_path(x) %>
<% end %>
```

Helper Path:

```
artist GET        /artists/:full_name(.:format)                                           artists#show {:full_name=>/[\w]+/}
```

Comment: Have you tried `<%= link_to "name", artist_path(x.full_name) %>`?

Comment: @jvillian I definitely have.  Keeping getting this `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"artists", :full_name=>"Jake"} missing required keys: [:full_name]`  Have no clue how the `full_name` is there yet it's missing.  So confused

Comment: Have you tried removing the constraint on your route to see if that makes a difference?